# Process: ru.mediaznak.test, PID: 6410 java.lang.NullPointerException at

Tags: android, java, исключения

В приложении используется такая схема:

1. Создаётся `AsyncTask`.
2. В `doInBackground()` идёт загрузка данных с сервера.
3. С помощью `try {} catch(IOException e){}` ловится ошибка загрузки, если таковая имеется.

Итог такой: при отсутствии интернета приложение просто вылетает с ошибкой...
Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы приложение при этом не вылетало, а выводило сообщение о проблеме с подключением?

**UPD**
Код на котором приложение падает:

```
try {
    items = json.getJSONArray("result");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Logcat:

> > Process: ru.mediaznak.test, PID: 6410 java.lang.NullPointerException
> >                 at ru.mediaznak.testvk.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:271)

Я так понимаю в json что-то не то

Comment: Покажите код `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Вестимо падает не с IOExecption, либо тру кетч не там где ошибка

Comment: и logCat тоже покажите.

Comment: Вылетает с ошибкой... какой? Покажите, что в блоке catch! doInBackground() в блоке try?

Answer (score 4):

```
final static int JSON_ERROR = 1;
final static int NETWORK_ERROR = 2;
final static int UNKNOWN_ERROR = 3;

int error = 0;
try {
    items = json.getJSONArray("result");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    error = JSON_ERROR;
} catch(IOException e) {
    error = NETWORK_ERROR;
} catch(Exception e) {
    error = UNKNOWN_ERROR;
}

//в onResult проверка error
```